# How to disable copy with group header in ag-grid-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have an requirement to disable only **copy with Group header** in my application I have tried to disable it using css but it does't work. please help me to disable it with proper config option.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this using css

```
body div.ag-menu-option:nth-child(4) {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure which context menu items are displayed by using strings from the pre-made list of built-in items or by building your own. [link to docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/context-menu/#configuring-the-context-menu)

> The result of getContextMenuItems(params) should be a list with each item either a) a string or b) a MenuItemDef. Use 'string' to pick from built in menu items and use MenuItemDef descriptions for your own menu items.

In my case I only wanted to show `Copy` and `Copy with Headers` so I used the following:

```
const getContextMenuItems = () => {
  return ['copy', 'copyWithHeaders'];
};

// ... then within the grid props:

getContextMenuItems={getContextMenuItems}
```